# Kinect and Unity3D : Mapping Kinect Joints with 3D model

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapping, kinect

I'm starting to learn and develop a Unity3D app with Kinect. I have troubles with mapping Joints from Kinect sensor into a 3D object or character. I received Joints data from BodySourceView.cs sample that SDK provides.

I can move around the Object and rotate it using just one joint, for example using hand joint to do something with a box.

I would like to move a character using all joints data that will be mapped into it. Is there any idea or tutorial that I should go through that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Open [this asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7747) from your unity with version 4.6.1

This Asset is providing that Your 3DCharacter will move for your Hand and Leg sensor inputs.

How to Run the Example:

1. Install the Kinect SDK 1.8 or Runtime 1.8 as explained in Readme-Kinect-MsSdk.pdf, located in Assets-folder.
2. Download and import that package.
3. Open and run scene KinectAvatarsDemo, located in Assets/AvatarsDemo-folder.
4. Open and run scene KinectGesturesDemo, located in Assets/GesturesDemo-folder.
5. Open and run scene KinectOverlayDemo, located in Assets/OverlayDemo-folder.
6. Open and run scene DepthColliderDemo, located in Assets/DepthColliderDemo-folder.